# Multiple nested \ifdefined statements

Tags: conditionals

I use the "variables" in my header and would like to shorten the code by combining `\ifdefined\@@author` and `\ifdefined\@group`. Searching the repository for "ifdefined multiple arguments" etc. didn't give a useful result. I experimented with `||`, as from different programming languages, but you can imagine... :)

Is there no easier way to do that?

```
\rhead{\small\color{darkgray2}%
    \ifdefined\@@author%
        \@@author%
        \ifdefined\@group%
            , %
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\@group%
        \@group%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\@@date%
        \linebreak\@@date%
    \fi%
}
```

Thanks.

Edit (MWE):

```
\LoadClass{article}
\newcommand\group[1]{\def\group{#1}}
\author{Me}
\group{Group}
\title{Work Hygiene and Safety}
\date{18th~September~2018}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% 

\makeatletter
\rhead{
    \ifdefined\@author%
        \@author%
        \ifdefined\group%
            , %
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\group%
        \group%
    \fi%
    \ifdefined\@date%
        \linebreak\@date%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see what logic changes would make this shorter: could you write out in pseudo-code what flow you are after?

Comment: I just want the learn "whats's possible". I thought there must be a solution like
\ifdefined\THIS&&THAT ...

Comment: @Steffen there are no boolean and and or connectives although of course any logical combination can be made with suitable `\if` combinations.

Comment: unrelated but you have `%` at the ends of exactly the wrong lines, you need one after `\rhead{` but the ones after command names like `\group%` do nothing as white space is ignored after a command name.

Comment: I would guess you intended `\newcommand\group[1]{\def\group{#1}}` to be `\newcommand\group[1]{\def\@group{#1}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of all TeX primitive conditionals is the same: they are 'one shot' tests with no combining logic. There are a variety of 'wrappers' which provide such logic, most notable in [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and [`expl3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), which use a more 'LaTeX-like' syntax. At the primitive level, one can create combinations by using `\ifnum` or `\ifodd`, for example

```
\ifnum0%
  \ifdefined\@@author 1\fi
  \ifdefined\@group 1\fi
  >0 %
  % Code for 'at least one is true' case
\else
  % Code for 'neither is true' case
\fi
```

This uses the fact that TeX keeps expanding material in the number test until it finds a non-numeral, in particular a comparator here. So the two `\ifdefined` tests get converted into either a value or nothing at all.